# Range Delete in AVL Tree

Tags: python-3.x, range, avl-tree

I need to delete a range in an AVL Tree. For now, I'm  implementing a function to delete all nodes with key less than `low`. However, my code is not working, and some nodes remain undeleted.

Interestingly, it appears that only one invalid node which is the nearest to `low` or `high` remains, for deleteLessThan and deleteGreaterThan.

[Source Code for my AVL Tree](https://pastebin.com/6Tb1VAu2)

More specifically, the code that is prolematic:

```
def deleteLessThan(self, root, high, equal):
    if root is None:
        return
    if root.left is not None:
        root.left = self.deleteLessThan(root.left, high, equal)
    if root.right is not None:
        root.right = self.deleteLessThan(root.right, high, equal)
    if root.key < high or (equal and root.key == high):
        root = self.delete(root, root.key, None)
    return root
```

4 is still present. (Test code)

Test Code:

```
tree = AVLTree()
root = None

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for i in a:
    root = tree.insert(root, i, i)

tree.deleteLessThan(root, 5, False)
print(tree.string(root))
```

I suspect the problem could be updating after deletion as `root.left` and `root.right` change after that, though I am not sure.

This is the same thing but done in a different order

```
 def deleteLessThan(self, root, high, equal):
    if root is None:
        return
    if root.key < high or (equal and root.key == high):
        root = self.delete(root, root.key, None)
    if root is None:
        return
    if root.left is not None:
        root.left = self.deleteLessThan(root.left, high, equal)
    if root.right is not None:
        root.right = self.deleteLessThan(root.right, high, equal)
    return root
```

3 is still present. (Test code)

Comment: Interesting problem, but i doubt your approach is correct.

Comment: Then what approach should I take?